# Inverse arctan composition

Tags: trigonometry

I need to solve the following without a calculator:

$$
\sin(\arctan^{-1}\sqrt{3}) =
$$

I was thinking the inverse of `arctan` must be just `tan`, which would give me:

$$
\sin(\tan\sqrt{3})
$$

But I don't know what to do next or if that's even correct.

Comment: Where did the first expression come from? Is it possible that the author wrote a typo? Maybe they were waffling on the decision between writing $\arctan$ or $\tan^{-1}$, and they accidentally ended up with $\arctan^{-1}$, but that's not what they intended.

Comment: $\arctan^{-1}$ as a notation is weird. Ask the source.

Comment: @ChrisCulter teacher's semeseter review packet. I was also wondering if it's a typo but it appears in more than one question.

Comment: Good to know. Something that's been written by a single person, with no editor, which has never been published in multiple editions, nor had errata distributed for any edition... yeah it could easily be a typo. Even if it's in more than one question, it could be a copy-paste error. As @SassatelliGiulio says, ask the teacher to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, this is probably a typo. The quantity $\sqrt 3$ is a reasonable value for the *slope* of a line, but it's a totally unreasonable value for the *angle* between two lines. That means it's reasonable to ask about $\arctan \sqrt 3$, but unreasonable to ask about $\tan \sqrt 3$. So the author probably meant $\arctan \sqrt 3$.

In a homework or study problem, any angle is probably going to be a rational multiple of $\pi$. If some other kind of number sneaks into a context where an angle is expected, that should set off alarm bells.

Comment: Confirmed it was an error.